# Ubuntu and windows 10 Dual-boot problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I want to uninstall ubuntu from my computer but when i do that steps that remove the partition it appears "No partition found"  it is because the GRUB problem 
Then i reinstall Ubuntu to take it back .

BUT my question is, if i replace the ubuntu boot to windows boot and then uninstall ubuntu ... it will make the GRUB problem "Partition not found" Again ???

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If Windows 10 pre-installed it should be UEFI, and if upgrade from Windows 7 probably BIOS? Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi